# Node.js - How to enforce data consistency with async waterfall?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a consistency/concurrency issue with my flow. When I create a session (`createSession` is executed from a route) in my app, several async steps are needed. The Mongoose model will only enforce consistency at the very end of the process, in the `function(err,result)` of the waterfall.

The problem is that if 2 requests are fired with a very short interval, step 2 might not be finished when step 1 starts for the second request, and it leads to data inconsistency. What is the best approach for this kind of problem? Is there a way to enqueue requests?

```
function createSession(req, res) {

async.waterfall([
    // Step 1 in collection 1
    function(callback){
        ...
    },

    // Step 2 in collection 2
    function(callback){
        ...
    },

    function(err,result){
        ... // session is created
    }
```

Comment: I would use a flag on the user (`creatingSession`) or limit `createSession` to be called once per `period` per user (don't know if a user should be creating more than 1 session per second)

Comment: async has a [queue control flow](https://github.com/caolan/async#queue). That being said, concurrency issues can frequently point to schema design issues. Throttling your app should really be a last ditch effort.